# How to define a nullable repeated field in protobuf 3

Tags: protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

In [protobuf 3](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/) how do you define a [nullable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type) `repeated` field? The user needs to know whether or not the field was ever set. The `optional` keyword does not work for `repeated` fields.
For example lets say we have a repeated field:

```
message Result {
  repeated string url = 1;
}
```

How can the user tell if `url` is set to it's default value of an empty array or never been set? In Java I would want to know the difference between `new String[0]` and `null`.

**Edit**: Looks like protobuf calls this [Field Presence](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/field_presence/) and there is not a direct way to express this in a `repeated` field.

Another thought I had was to use `oneof` but protobuf 3 [does not support](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#oneof) the `repeat` fields directly.

> You then add your oneof fields to the oneof definition. You can add
> fields of any type, except map fields and repeated fields.

Comment: Edited my answer with you clarifying that you meant the *collection*, not the *elements* - but yeah, protobuf just can't express this - "no message" and "an empty collection" are both usually encoded by simply writing *nothing* (zero bytes), so... nothing to distinguish; in protobuf-net (for .NET, as the name suggests) I have something called "null wrapped collections" which makes this easy to express, but... (shrugs)

Comment: Looks like it's possible to support tracking presence in a packed repeated field to distinguish "no message" and "an empty collection" since it uses the same `LEN` wire type as `bytes`. It's just it's not implemented in the library. I think maybe we can open an issue for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a thing that protobuf can express directly; to tell whether individual elements are `null` or not, you would need to add a layer, which is exactly what `StringValue` in [wrappers.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto#L112-L115) does, so:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
message Result {
    repeated StringValue urls = 1;
}
```

To tell whether the *collection* is `null` or not, again, you'd need to add a layer, perhaps:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";
message Result {
    HazUrls maybe = 1;
}
message HazUrls {
    repeated string urls = 1;
}
```

Then `result.maybe` can be `null` or can be a message that *has* a set of urls (which can be zero length)

And if you need to tell whether the collection is `null` *and* whether any of the elements are `null`, you need to combine the two. This starts adding a lot of layers very quickly!